# I need help depositing my money into my kraken account

Tags: ether

i was wodering how to exactly deposit money into my kraken account. I am on the part where I pick my deposit method, and i click on the amount i want and shows me a address and other things like that, and at this point im stuck, i have all my information on my bank and whatnot,but now im just stuck. anything would help a lot

Comment: Have you read their help pages? https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/215791158-How-do-I-deposit-USD-into-my-account-US-Resident- https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/201648143-How-do-I-make-a-deposit-

Comment: What is the type of "my money"?  Is it fiat or crypto currency?  (Someone has flagged this as off-topic, and please edit your question: as it is, it's not clear whether the tag "ether" is appropriate.)

Comment: my money as in bank money and its in the bank, and i taged ether because it my first time here

Comment: i did read the kraken support but all it tells me is how to set it up, not helping me deposit. it gives me a name and address, and i dont know what to do, if i have to send money over there, or contact that person, or something

Comment: You have to contact them.  This has been flagged again and it is off-topic.  Perhaps try http://reddit.com/r/ethereum.